# How to automatically use the prefix of cleveref when refering to figures/tables in a published source?

Tags: cleveref

I would like to refer to a figure in a published source, e.g., Figure 2.10 in *Published Book* . Since I use cleveref to automatically add the prefix for all my other references, I would also prefer to stick with cleveref in this case for consistency: When I want to change the reference format, I don't have to come to these cases and fix them manually. How can I do this?

I would like it to look like

```
\someref{2.10} in~\cite{somesource}
```

Comment: could you provide a snippet of how you'd like the `.tex` source to look for this sentence?

Comment: @cmhughes See my edit.

Comment: something like `\newcommand{\someref}[1]{Figure~#1}`?

Comment: @cmhughes Yes, but it should comply with the customization of cleveref.

Comment: Do you have access to the original LaTeX files (including the main `aux` file) of *Published Book*? If not, how is LaTeX supposed to infer or otherwise determine the type (`figure`, `table`, `equation`, etc) and number ("2.1", etc) of the object being cross-referenced? Are you, i.e., the author, going to supply this information manually? A separate issue: do you load `hyperref` as well?

Comment: @Mico I do not mean to use label from that source. I can input the type manually, but I need to make sure the prefix is consistent with the rest of the paper.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cleveref}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\mycref}[1]{\@nameuse{cref@#1@name}}
\newcommand{\myCref}[1]{\@nameuse{Cref@#1@name}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
I would like to refer to a figure in a published source, e.g.,
\mycref{figure} 2.10 in Published Book. 

\myCref{figure} 2.10 in Published Book is a very nice picture.

\end{document}
```